# Jquery Mobile Post to PHP (same page)

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile

Not sure what I'm missing, the value won't post. I would like the code to post to the current page (test.php)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit_response").click(function() {
         $.post(test.php, {name: 'demo'}, success: function(data) {

         });
     });    
});
</script>


<a href="#" id="submit_response" data-role="button" data-theme="a">Demo Save</a>

<?php if(isset($_POST['name'])) echo 'Posted: '.$_POST['name'];?>
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Are you trying to reload the same page or update the page without reloading it? It seems like your doing half of each...

Comment: You can do this without javascript, using HTML form and post method. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: I'm trying to use the AJAX post,for learning, instead of a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that your content would'nt be updated with  `<?php if(isset($_POST['name'])) echo 'Posted: '.$_POST['name'];?>`

To make it work you can do like this :

1st create a function called `update()` or everything you want in bottom of all your html after any content

**UPDATE FUNCTION :**

```
<?php
function update(){
    if(isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name'] == "demo" ) {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($_POST['name'])    ;
        exit(); // To avoid full html page be delivered
    }
}
?>
```

AND CALL IT BEFORE ALL YOUR HTML OR ANY CONTENT
`<?php update(); ?>`

Then your javascript to update your page :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit_response").click(function() {
        $.post(<?php echo '"'.$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'].'"' ?>, {name: 'demo'}, dataType:"json", 
            success: function(data) {
                    $("#contentToUpdate").html(data.name);
            });
    }); 
});

</script>
```

Comment: This will send the data, however wont do anything else and apparently he needs the feedback, so you'll have to add a redirect in the post function.