# jQuery AJAX Refresh after Insert not working

Tags: php, jquery

I have a single page website, I have the insert working correctly, but I cannot seem to update the #results div after submit. The values are being inserted into the database just fine and if I hard refresh they are appearing. But not with the jQuery AJAX refresh. I am new to Ajax, so any help would be really appreciated, and any comments on code structure or bad habits, please comment as I am trying to learn the proper way to program.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){        

$("form#addTodo").submit(function(){
    alert('hello world'); // ensure function is running

    var post_title = $('input#post_title').val(); // take values from inputs
    var post_content = $('input#post_content').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "add.php",
        data: "post_title=" + post_title + "&post_content=" + post_content,
        success: function() {
            // alert('success'); // ensure success
            $('#results').fadeOut('slow').load('include/results.php').fadeIn('slow');               
        }
    });


    $('input#post_title').val(''); // clear form fields
    $('input#post_content').val('');

    return false; 
});
```

});

Here is the results.php file:

```
<?php

$sql = $db->query('SELECT id, post_title, post_content FROM posts ORDER BY post_title ASC');

$results = $sql->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$count_posts = count($results);

?>

<?php if ( have_posts() == true) : ?>
    <div class="accordion" id="accordion_main">
        <?php foreach($results as $entry): ?>
            <div class="accordion-group">
                <div class="accordion-heading">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion_main" href="#collapse-<?php echo $entry->id; ?>">    
                        <?php echo $entry->post_title; ?>
                    </a>    
                </div>
                <div id="collapse-<?php echo $entry->id; ?>" class="accordion-body collapse">   
                    <div class="accordion-inner">
                        <p class="target"><?php echo $entry->post_content; ?></p>
                        <p><a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $entry->id; ?>">Edit</a> <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $entry->id; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this post?');">Delete</a></p>                    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>                
    </div>
<?php else: ?>
    <h3>There are no posts to display at this time.</h3>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This works fine when it is included by the index.php, I just can't get it to refresh after posting the data to the DB.

```
<?php
require_once 'includes/db.php';
require_once 'includes/functions.php';
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="results">
<?php include_once 'includes/results.php'; ?>
</div>

<hr />
<p>Add New Post</p>

<form id="addTodo" action="">

<div>
    <label for="post_title">Post Title</label>
    <input id="post_title" name="post_title">
</div>

<div>
    <label for="post_content">Post Content</label>
    <input id="post_content" name="post_content">
</div>

<div>
    <button id="submit" type="submit">
        Save
    </button>
</div>

</form>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I should mention that I haven't put in form validation yet. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just return the data from success? and use that to make your html input

```
success:function(returnedData) {
     if (returnedData.status = 'successful') {
       //use javascript to append the data for example like 
       //returnedData.message to make html and insert into your current html
     }    
}
```

Note: returnedData has to be pushed out by your php in an json format.

Answer (score 0):

you can find a similar answer to your request if you read this thread that I had recently answered : [Jquery Mobile Post to PHP (same page)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14446770/1623591)

But you must make some adaptation for you context ;-) !!
I think that is the unique solution if you're using unique file script

Answer (score 0):

To insert data returned from php file just use $("element id or class").html() function to insert the data or html to specific area of your document